# Vb messagebox click no and keep text properties

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, messagebox

I have a button that clears all text and combobox fields, I would like to give the user a yes or no option to have a yes clear all fields and no leave them the way they were when the button was clicked. I have the code for the yes option i just need the no part. Thanks.

```
 Private Sub btnNewForm_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNewForm.Click

    MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to clear the form", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm Delete")

    If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then


            For Each ctrl In Controls
                If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
                    ctrl.Text = String.Empty
                End If
            Next

    ElseIf MsgBoxResult.No Then

     ??????????????????

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you dont need `ElseIf` - you dont want it to do anything, right?

Comment: Just don't do anything in the `MsgBoxResult.No` block. In fact, you can just remove it completely... Maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: well when i click no, all text fields that have something in them get cleared out still. So there has to be something in the no click code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the results of your MessageBox:

```
Dim results As DialogResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to clear the form", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm Delete")

If results = DialogResult.Yes Then
  For Each ctrl In Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
      ctrl.Text = String.Empty
    End If
  Next
End If
```

There is no reason to do anything for "No" since you don't want to change anything in regards to that answer.

Comment: Ok, this makes more sense. Thanks. Oh and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use that correctly. What you are actually doing there is....: Compare MsgboxResult.Yes with True.
Note that MsgBox() is actually a function that returns the button the user has clicked.
So do

```
Dim res as MsgBoxResult = MsgBox(...)
If res = MsgBoxResult.Yes then
  'Code for Yes
Else
  'Code for No
Endif
```

The MsgBox() function is also legacy VB6 stuff. It would be better to use

```
Dim res as DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Message", "Title", ...)
```